# Change browser engine in Phonegap application in IOS

Tags: ios, phonegap-desktop-app

Is it possible to change browser engine in Phonegap application in IOS? I want to change it because there are some errors because of UIWebView that is used by Phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Apple only allow to use Safari's Rendering Engine (WebKit) and Apple will reject your app if you use another rendering engine.

Read more at http://www.howtogeek.com/184283/why-third-party-browsers-will-always-be-inferior-to-safari-on-iphone-and-ipad/